# Unexpected DTD declaration error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

XslCompiledTransform sometimes throws an error: "Unexpected DTD declaration."
But most times it work. Here is the piece of code:

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsl.Load(Server.MapPath("~/TestSite/OpenAccess/XmlToHtml.xsl"));
xsl.Transform(restfullUrl, writer);
```

It is the fourth line that throws the error.

What I am doing is converting some XML(being served by a rest service at restfullUrl) to HTML.

Beats me. Anyone notice something weird here? Any thoughts?

Comment: This is too simple to have the error. You should be checking the inputs scanning for an error. Maybe a try catch, where on that error you write out the input into a log file.

Comment: I checked the stream being returned from the restfullUrl and it was returning malformed XML sporadically.

Comment: The error message is referring to something in your XML, it has nothing to do with your C# code.

Comment: yes michael...it was a problem with the service...it was returning malformed XML sporadically.